# SearchBar text empty when searchBarSearchButtonClicked called

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I've implemented the searchBarSearchButtonClicked delegate method in my view controller

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    searchBar.text = textView.text
}
```

The method is successfully called when the "Search" button is clicked but the searchBar.text property is empty.

Any ideas why searchBar.text would be empty?

Comment: is there any value in textView.text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the value from "searchBar.text" instead of assigning the value of the "textView.text" to it. Try this:

Comment this "searchBar.text = textView.text" and add "NSLog(@"%@",searchBar.text);"

Check in your log the value of the search bar now. You could also check your XIB file, if you have connected your search bar's delegate to your File's owner.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I followed you advice and got it working.  Thanks again.